# Adding a class to a map

Tags: c++, class, dictionary

I am trying to add a class object to a map, this is what I have:

```
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student{
    int PID;
    string name;
    int academicYear;
public:
    Student(int, string, int);
};

Student::Student (int P, string n, int a) {
    PID = P;
    name = n;
    academicYear = a;
}

void createStudent(map<string, Student>);

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    map <string, Student> studentList;

    createStudent(studentList);
}


void createStudent(map<string, Student> studentList){

    int PID;
    string name;
    int academicYear;

    cout << "Add new student-\nName: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "PID: ";
    cin >> PID;
    cout << "Academic year: ";
    cin >> academicYear;

    Student newstud (PID, name, academicYear);

    studentList[name] = newstud;  //this line causes the error: 
                                  //no matching function for call to 
                                  //'Student::Student()'
}
```

I don't understand why the constructor function is being called there, I thought newstud would already have been constructed from the previous line. Can anyone explain what is happening when I try to add newstud to the map?

Comment: Read a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). Also note that your changes to `studentList` aren't going to have any effect.

Comment: You are passing by value.  Your error is no different if you attempted to passed an `int` argument and expected that `int` to magically change when the function returns.  Instead, pass by reference.

Answer (score 2):

- Problem 1st

[*`std::map::operator[]`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will insert new element into container if its not present, using default constructor, which in your case is not present and will probably doesn't make sense even if you provide one.

So use [*`std::map::insert`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) for such scenario

- Problem 2nd

Even if you successfully insert using `studentList.insert(std::make_pair(name, newstud));` its not going to reflect changes in original map `studentList` in `main ( )` unless you use a reference type, in function definition & declaration of `createStudent`

So use

```
void createStudent(map<string, Student>& );
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add entries using the function, you should make your parameter `studentList` pass by reference.

And instead of

```
studentList[name] = newstud;
```

use:

```
studentList.insert(std::make_pair(name, newstud));
```

Just a suggestion, though.

Comment: Its not just a suggestion btw